# Why won't this function give me the name of the element it's bound to?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an some html elements defined with class="tab".

And in my jquery file, I have defined the following function:

```
  $('.tab').mouseleave( function() {
    alert($(this).name);
  });
```

When I trigger the mouseleave, for the element of class "tab", with the name "Contact", I do get the alert - but it says "undefined". I was expecting to see "Contact".

What does $(this) give me - does it actually give me the DOM element?

NB. Ultimately, I want to be able to work out on what side ( north, south, east or west ) the mouse left the element. So I'm doing this alert thing to ensure that I actually have access to the width and height of that element. So far, I don't seem to have access to that info.

Comment: The `name` attribute should only be used on `input` elements.

Comment: what do you mean by name? is it an attribute or is it the tagname you are referring to?

Comment: @spaceman12 did you give me a -1?

Comment: *"What does $(this) give me"* ... see here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`name` is a native javascript method, you are working with `$(this)`, which is a jQuery object, and not the native DOM element, that would be just `this` :

```
$('.tab').mouseleave( function() {
   alert(this.name);
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cxdPK/)

Comment: Ah, *someone* finally used the DOM instead of wrapping everything in needless jQuery methods. +1 =)

Comment: @adeneo does this work inside a jQuery $(document).ready() function?

Comment: @DavidThomas - Thats why I decided to answer even though there where six other answers. BeeBand, yes it works everywhere!

Answer (score 1):

`$(this)` gives you a jQuery object that wraps the native DOM element.

`this` is the DOM element you seek.

[this](http://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified/) is where you may find a more comprehensive description.

Answer (score 1):

`$(this)` will give you the JQuery object.

`this` gives you the DOM element.

You can get the name by calling `$(this).prop('name')` if the "name" attribute is supported by that HTML element.

The "name" attribute is currently only supported by form elements (input, select, textarea, form); the "name" part of the name-value pairs that are sent to the server when a POST verb is sent to the server (i.e. you post a form with the "POST" method).

Further reading:

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/please-explain-attr-vs-prop-change-in-1-6

[.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

http://timmywillison.com/2011/When-to-use-.attr()-and-.prop().html

Answer (score 1):

The name is an attribute, right?
So check $(this).attr('name')

Comment: .attr() was depreciated in place of .prop() a few versions ago.

Comment: prop() doesn't appear to work for me ( 'undefined' ) but attr() does.

Comment: @Spikeh where do you see an attr is deprecated? http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/

Comment: I'm a bit wrong :) .prop() is preferred, because .attr()'s implementation often gets properties and attributes confused (prior to JQuery 1.6 anyway).

The OP is asking to retrieve the "name" attribute of an unspecified tag. The "name" attribute should only exist on form attributes, and if it exists on other elements, it is syntactically incorrect... so .prop() will return undefined. .attr() will retrieve any attribute - i.e. $("div").attr('thisisatest') will retrieve the "thisisatest" attribute from all divs, but "thisisatest" is not a valid attribute.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery allows you to get the width and the height like this:

`$(this).height(); //is the computed height eg. 200 without the dimension`

For your specific code example, try `$(this).prop('name');` or `$(this).attr('name'); //now deprecated`

this will pick up `foo` from `<input name="foo" />`

You could also try `this.name` if your element has a name attribute, which should only be applied to `input` elements. However it may return undefined and throw an error if you don't have the attribute.

`$(this)` is a jQuery object with the DOM element inside it. `this` is the DOM element direct.

Answer (score 1):

You are working with jQuery object, use `attr` or `prop` function to get attribute value:

```
$('.tab').mouseleave( function() {
    // either should work
    alert($(this).attr('name'));
    alert($(this).prop('name'));
});
```

Comment: .attr() was depreciated in place of .prop() a few versions ago.

Comment: It's not, `attr` is for attributes, and `prop` is for properties, even though they both mostly work, there are certain preferred uses, and in many cases `prop` should be used intead of `attr`, and especially so on properties.

Comment: ok, I'm not quite right then - .prop() is preferred, as .attr() can often get properties and attributes confused - See this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr

Answer (score 1):

```
     $('.tab').mouseleave( function() {
    alert($(this).attr('name'));
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because $ gives an array of wrapped elements. Thus $(this) will be an array with one element. $(this).attr("name") will give you the name since attr knows it is an array. If you want you can use $(this)[0].name or simply this.name